# customize the path of job files in spring batch admin manager

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

[Spring batch admin](http://ttps://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin) manager loads the job files from war's `classpath:/META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/` directory.

I'd like to put my job xml files in `c:\` or *some other external location*.

Is it possible in batch admin manager to override/customize the directory location to an external location?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after clearly reading the spring batch admin user guide. Override the 'jobloader' bean in execution-context.xml.

To be precise, create a context file named 'execution-context.xml' and declare your customized options for the bean named 'jobloader'. This overrides the configuration for this particular named bean in the bootstrap/execution-context.xml. Refer spring batch admin user guide for more details.